# Do image sizes in Xcode need to be exactly the 1x/2x/3x ratio?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I've got my images in the sizes of 128px, 256px and 512px. This makes them actually 1x,2x,4x. I've added them so 128px is @1x, 256px is @2x, and 512px is @3x. Will this be a problem? Do the images need to be exactly that 1x, 2x, 3x ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason we're using 1x,2x,3x resolutions is to show the best possible resolution on a variety of display sizes. If you're mistagging your images it could cause undesirable effects. I'm not talking about fatal problems, but still as an app developer you should aim for perfection and use the image sizes as recommended by the Human interface guidelines. 
Avoiding downscaling and upscaling (by providing the correct image sizes) will result in a much nicer user interface and also less processing on the fly.

It is simple to resize the images in most photo editors, if you have many you can do a batch job in Photoshop or in the free ImageMagick command line tools.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. It will work but it's best to go with the recommended sizes.

Answer (score 1):

No its not a problem but be exact in the case of app Icons otherwise you will get error when you'll do this with app icons